# How to print the contents of a WPF control without using a PrintDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to print a WPF control's content without using PrintDialog? I want to avoid PrintDialog because its PrinterSettings.PrintToFile property is ignored unless the user checks it in the dialog. I need to print to a "FILE:" port without showing a print dialog or asking the user to provide a file name.

I looked into PrintDocument which does have the silent PrintToFile capability, but I couldn't find a way to draw the contents of my WPF control onto the document.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file format does not matter you can generate an image from the WPF control which you can then save to a file:

```
private static RenderTargetBitmap ConvertToBitmap(UIElement uiElement, double resolution)
    {
        dynamic scale = resolution / 96.0;
        uiElement.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        dynamic sz = uiElement.DesiredSize;
        dynamic rect = new Rect(sz);
        uiElement.Arrange(rect);
        dynamic bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(scale * (rect.Width)), Convert.ToInt32(scale * (rect.Height)), scale * 96, scale * 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        bmp.Render(uiElement);
        return bmp;
    }
```

If however you are after something like a postscript output or text file output then this won't be suitable.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing that, and then drawing the bitmap to the PrintDocument's Graphics in the PrintPage handler. Worked great.